# Windows 7 system image: Previous increment not visible in Explorer

Tags: windows-7, backup, vhd, disk-image, windows-7-backup

I tried out the backup tool built into *Windows 7 Pro x64.* In the help text, it says: *"If you're saving your system images on an internal or external drive, or on CDs or DVDs, you can keep several versions of system images."*

What I did as a test:

1. Attached a USB 3 HDD with ca. 600 GB of free space.
2. Using Windows 7's *Backup and Restore*, created a system image of the ca. 200 GB
   system drive. This includes the two standard Windows 7 partitions: *(C:)* and *System
   Reserved:*

   [image: Annotated screenshot of partition selection in Backup and Restore]
3. Made a small change, adding text in a file, which would allow me later to compare
   different increments.
4. Made another system backup using *Backup and Restore*.

Now, when I look at the USB drive, I only find one `.vhd` file per partition, with time stamp of the backup from step 4:

[image: Annotated screenshot of Explorer showing contents of backup directory]

*Does this mean that no increment has been created, i.e. the first backup has been overwritten? Can there perhaps be only one increment per day?*

Comment: Maybe it's simply saving increments in original files. Try to initiate backup restoration and see if both backups will be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in a 2009 TechNet article
[“Learn more about system image backup”](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2009/10/31/learn-more-about-system-image-backup.aspx):

> During the first backup, the backup engine scans the source drive and copies
>   only blocks that contain data into a .vhd file stored on the target, creating
>   a compact view of the source drive. The next time a system image is created,
>   only new and changed data is written to the .vhd file, and old data on the
>   same block is moved out of the VHD and into the shadow copy storage area.
>   Volume Shadow Copy Service is used to compute the changed data between
>   backups, as well as to handle the process of moving the old data out to the
>   shadow copy area on the target. This approach makes the backup fast (since
>   only changed blocks are backed up) and efficient (since data is stored in a
>   compact manner). When restoring the image, blocks will be restored to their
>   original locations on the source disk. If you want to restore from an older
>   backup, the engine reads from the shadow copy area and restores the
>   appropriate blocks.

In a nutshell: Only the last backup is displayed in Windows Explorer. Previous
increments are stored in the shadow copy storage area *on the backup medium.*

How VHDs from previous increments can be accessed for attaching using Windows
7’s *Disk Management* is not clear to me.